# Filezilla alternate for non-FTP browsing

Tags: windows-explorer, filezilla, browsing

I'm looking for a program where I can sync the browsing of two file locations and easily drag and drop between them. Basically the exact same thing as Filezilla, but with two local sites (not limited to using an FTP site).

Any suggestions?

Comment: We don't give software recomendations but most file syncing software would allow for something like this

Answer (score 1):

Free commander is a good alternative http://www.freecommander.com/

Comment: Gave it a try, couldn't find a way to sync the browsing (as in clicking on a folder named X in the left will also open the corresponding folder on the right in 2 mirrored directories) Also there are a few other things I find a little un-intuitive for my liking. Thanks though.

Comment: Read [this post](http://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/47225), you must.